# Scripts with asyc attribute still block other script execution

Tags: javascript, performance

NOTE: I didn't develop this site - I just have to deal with it.

I have a document with LAB.js being used to asynchronously load a series of scripts in the head. Further down I have two more external scripts, one further down in the head, and the other at the top of the body.

Those two scripts are often unreachable. They're both marked as 'async' and don't block the document from loading. HOWEVER - they do evidently block the other scripts from executing.

To be clear, the first series of scripts are downloaded immediately, but won't seem to execute until the other two async scripts are downloaded.

The site isn't public, and this type of issue can't be created in jsfiddle. A crude illustration:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
     <!-- This script asynchronously loads many others -->
     <script src="/js/LAB.js"></script>

     <script src="slow-server/js/slowscript1.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
     <script src="show-server/js/slowscript2.js" async></script>
</body>
```

Info on Lab.js: http://labjs.com/

LAB will prepend several other script tags to the head to be loaded asynchronously. They're all downloaded right away, but will not execute until the "slow-server" scripts respond. Sometimes takes a while. This seems to me incorrect behavior for scripts with the async attribute (and I'm testing in Chrome). Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement):

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these
>   attributes. If the async attribute is present, then the script will be
>   executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the async
>   attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the
>   script is executed when the page has finished parsing. If neither
>   attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed
>   immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

So, when a script has async, it will be fetched immediately from the server, but DOM parsing will continue in parallel.  That part is easy and clear.

Then, as soon as the async script has been fetched, it will be executed.  This execution may be before or after the DOM has finished loading depending purely upon timing of how things took to load/parse and it may be before or after other non-async scripts in the page have run.

Note, that because javascript in a browser is single threaded, once this async script starts to execute, no other scripts will run until this script finishes, even though it was "async".  Async on the scripts allows the parsing of the DOM to continue (rather than block), but it does not keep the script from executing once it is available and once it executes, other processing has to wait for it to complete executing.

If you want the script to NOT execute until after the DOM and any regular scripts in the DOM have loaded and run, then you should use "defer", not "async".

FYI, if you want to wade through the actual specifications for all this it's [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script).

---

If you want a more detailed explanation of how all this applies to your exact situation, you will have to at least give us a pseudo-code representation of what scripts you're asking about as your words aren't clear enough to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description. The only part I don't fully comprehend is that the other scripts are blocked while the two asynchronous ones are fetched, not while they're being executed. In my most recent test the to slow-server scripts took 3 minutes to respond and download. The other scripts failed to execute for that entire time. Still, I'll try defer and see if that behaves differently.

Comment: @Dygerati - there are other things at play here.  A browser has a maximum number of connections that it will open at once, thus a maximum number of things it will download at once.  So, if you have several large things being downloaded (even though async), some non async things might get stuck in line behind them due to the connection limit.

Comment: @Dygerati - Also, remember that once a script has been fetched, it will in the browser cache and, from then on, will likely load nearly immediately from the browser cache.  This will probably make it behave almost as if it is not async.  Async applies to the time to load the script so if it loads immediately from the browser cache, then async doesn't do much.  Perhaps you want "defer" instead to make sure these scripts aren't executed until after the DOM has been parsed and any non-defer, non-async scripts have been run.